# Make nav dropdown show above all other divs

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins, css-position

I have a page I'm working on where currently I have 2 items.  Item 1 is a flexnav jQuery navigation menu with a dropdown.  Item 2 is a slick jQuery div scroller.  I am trying to position the slick scroller just below the flexnav menu.  The problem I'm running into though is when you hover over one of the menu items the dropdown for the sub menu is covered up by the slick scroller divs.  This only seems to be happening with a screen larger than 800px as the flexnav plugin changes to a mobile friendly navigation menu on small screens.

I have tried changing the css position setting of both items but I just can't seem to figure out how to make the dropdown menus appear above the slick divs.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here or have any suggestions on how I could change things around to achieve what I am looking for?

[Here is a example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/8b4yh3de/)

The code I am using:

```
<header>
    <nav style="background-color: #FAD10E; height:50px">
    <div class="menu-button">Mobile Menu</div>
        <ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stuff</a>

            <!-- THIS DROPDOWN IS COVERED BY THE AUTOPLAY DIV -->
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stuff 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/">Stuff 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stuff 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stuff 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Stuff 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<div>
    <!-- THIS AUTOPLAY DIV SHOWS ON TOP OF THE MENU DROPDOWN ITEMS -->
    <div class="autoplay">
        <div><img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/assets/images/fade/happy-home-care-client.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/assets/images/fade/helping-hands-home-care.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/assets/images/fade/loving-home-care-client.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to add two lines of CSS

## [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b4yh3de/1/)

**CSS**

```
.flexnav{
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    width:90%;
    position: relative; /* <-- Added */
    z-index: 1; /* <-- Added */
}
```

The `position: relative` allows for the element to have a z-index applied (an element must not be statically positioned, relative positioning will allow the element to display in normal document flow without having a `static` positioning).

The `z-index: 1` provides a separate stacking context for the nav.  Otherwise, because it precedes your carousel in document flow, will necessarily display beneath it when overlapped without a `z-index` given.

Stacking contexts apply *generally* only to elements which sit at the same hierarchical depth.  So putting the flyout in your nav with a higher `z-index`won't work.

Comment: Sometimes, using z-index:1; is not enough, you don't know what other plugin he's using that also has z-index in it so better add z-index:9999; just to be safe, anyway, +1 for adding explanation. :D

Comment: @Alin - That's actually, in my opinion, incredibly bad practice.  Putting an arbitrary `z-index` then means that you're forced to keep these random values in your own head. I can see an argument for giving some flexibility for inserting items _in between_ subsequent `z-index`es, and perhaps incrementing by something like 10, but I hate the whole "Let's throw a bunch of 9s in this `z-index` and hope it's a high enough number."  It just screams lazy.  And then it's an arms-race between plugins and your codes for who can throw the most `9`s in the `z-index` value.

Comment: I would agree with you if we were talking about someone who know's what he's doing and what to look for, but since we are not and the author of the question doesn't know about z-index, this might not work  if he had other pieces of code and he wouldn't know why. In my own and personal opinion, I believe it's a compromise work making for someone who's just starting to learn CSS.

Comment: @Alin - Yeah, I was guilty of this when I first started designing websites, but I wish I had learned better early on looking back on things like `z-index: 999999999;` in CSS.  You start to get the impression that just adding more `9`s will somehow magically generate a higher stacking context.

Comment: I have heard of z-index but was never super sure of how to us them correctly.  Thank you so much for the explanation.  You have made me a better code because of it! As for the number argument I feel indifferent about it.  999 feels sloppy but in the end it still works just fine.

Comment: fiddle link broken